# BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Observe the following problem:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS("""
<a href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update">
    Edit
</a>
""")

# This returns the <a> element
soup.find(
    'a',
    href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update",
    text=re.compile(".*Edit.*")
)

soup = BS("""
<a href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
""")

# This returns None
soup.find(
    'a',
    href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update",
    text=re.compile(".*Edit.*")
)
```

For some reason, BeautifulSoup will not match the text, when the `<i>` tag is there as well. Finding the tag and showing its text produces

```
>>> a2 = soup.find(
        'a',
        href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update"
    )
>>> print(repr(a2.text))
'\n Edit\n'
```

Right. According to the [Docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression), soup uses the match function of the regular expression, not the search function. So I need to provide the DOTALL flag:

```
pattern = re.compile('.*Edit.*')
pattern.match('\n Edit\n')  # Returns None

pattern = re.compile('.*Edit.*', flags=re.DOTALL)
pattern.match('\n Edit\n')  # Returns MatchObject
```

Alright. Looks good. Let's try it with soup

```
soup = BS("""
<a href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
""")

soup.find(
    'a',
    href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update",
    text=re.compile(".*Edit.*", flags=re.DOTALL)
)  # Still return None... Why?!
```

#### **Edit**

My solution based on geckons answer: I implemented these helpers:

```
import re

MATCH_ALL = r'.*'


def like(string):
    """
    Return a compiled regular expression that matches the given
    string with any prefix and postfix, e.g. if string = "hello",
    the returned regex matches r".*hello.*"
    """
    string_ = string
    if not isinstance(string_, str):
        string_ = str(string_)
    regex = MATCH_ALL + re.escape(string_) + MATCH_ALL
    return re.compile(regex, flags=re.DOTALL)


def find_by_text(soup, text, tag, **kwargs):
    """
    Find the tag in soup that matches all provided kwargs, and contains the
    text.

    If no match is found, return None.
    If more than one match is found, raise ValueError.
    """
    elements = soup.find_all(tag, **kwargs)
    matches = []
    for element in elements:
        if element.find(text=like(text)):
            matches.append(element)
    if len(matches) > 1:
        raise ValueError("Too many matches:\n" + "\n".join(matches))
    elif len(matches) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return matches[0]
```

Now, when I want to find the element above, I just run `find_by_text(soup, 'Edit', 'a', href='/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update')`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The problem is that your `<a>` tag with the `<i>` tag inside, doesn't have the `string` attribute you expect it to have. First let's take a look at what `text=""` argument for `find()` does.

NOTE: The `text` argument is an old name, since BeautifulSoup 4.4.0 it's called `string`.

From the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument):

> Although string is for finding strings, you can combine it with
>   arguments that find tags: Beautiful Soup will find all tags whose
>   .string matches your value for string. This code finds the  tags
>   whose .string is “Elsie”:
>
> ```
> soup.find_all("a", string="Elsie")
> # [<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>]
> ```

Now let's take a look what `Tag`'s `string` attribute is (from the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) again):

> If a tag has only one child, and that child is a NavigableString, the
>   child is made available as .string:
>
> ```
> title_tag.string
> # u'The Dormouse's story'
> ```

(...)

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what
>   .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None:
>
> ```
> print(soup.html.string)
> # None
> ```

This is exactly your case. Your `<a>` tag contains a text **and** `<i>` tag. Therefore, the find gets `None` when trying to search for a string and thus it can't match.

**How to solve this?**

Maybe there is a better solution but I would probably go with something like this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS("""
<a href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
""")

links = soup.find_all('a', href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update")

for link in links:
    if link.find(text=re.compile("Edit")):
        thelink = link
        break

print(thelink)
```

I think there are not too many links pointing to `/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update` so it should be fast enough.

Comment: Right. Okay. That explains the cause of the issue. Thanks. How would you remedy that? The objectice remains to find the <a> tag containing the text "Edit"

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I am doing? You use the text parameter of the find method. Looking at your example, this would produce the same result as my code

Comment: @Eldamir The difference is that I'm looking inside the `<a>` tags. Try it yourself, it works.

Answer (score 89):

in one line using lambda

```
soup.find(lambda tag:tag.name=="a" and "Edit" in tag.text)
```

Comment: Will help when there is any br tag in the tag we are looking for, beacuse soup.find_all("a", string="Elsie") will fail in that case

Comment: Will also help with when you are using BeautifulSoup 3

Answer (score 17):

You can pass a [*function*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) that return `True` if `a` *text* contains "Edit" to `.find`

```
In [51]: def Edit_in_text(tag):
   ....:     return tag.name == 'a' and 'Edit' in tag.text
   ....: 

In [52]: soup.find(Edit_in_text, href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update")
Out[52]: 
<a href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update">
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
```

---

EDIT:

You can use the [**`.get_text()`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method instead of the `text` in your function which gives the same result:

```
def Edit_in_text(tag):
    return tag.name == 'a' and 'Edit' in tag.get_text()
```

Answer (score 8):

With [soupsieve 2.1.0](https://github.com/facelessuser/soupsieve/releases/tag/2.1.0) you can use `:-soup-contains` css pseudo class selector to target a node's text. This replaces the deprecated form of `:contains()`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS("""
<a href="/customer-menu/1/accounts/1/update">
    Edit
</a>
""")
single = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Edit")').text.strip()
multiple = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('a:-soup-contains("Edit")')]
print(single, '\n', multiple)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. **Method - 1:** Checking text property

```
    pattern = 'Edit'
    a2 = soup.find_all('a', string = pattern)[0]
```

2. **Method - 2:** Using lambda iterate through all elements

```
    a2 = soup.find(lambda tag:tag.name=="a" and "Edit" in tag.text)
```

## Good Luck