# Python + BeautifulSoup: How to get wrapper out of HTML based on text?

Tags: python, html, css, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Would like to get the wrapper of a key text. For example, in HTML:

```
…
<div class=“target”>chicken</div>
<div class=“not-target”>apple</div>
…
```

And by based on the text “chicken”, would like to get back `<div class=“target”>chicken</div>`.

Currently, have the following to fetch the HTML:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get(url).txt
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, ‘html.parser’)
```

And having to just do `soup.find_all(‘div’,…)` and loop through all available `div` to find the wrapper that I am looking for.

But without having to loop through every `div`, What would be the proper and most optimal way of fetching the wrapper in HTML based on a defined text?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to accept/upvote answer!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959218/4387299

Comment: @internety Gave e.g. `soup.find_all('div', string='chicken')` a try but just returns an empty array.

Comment: don't use curly quotes

Comment: read whole answer I pointed you to before saying anything more :)

Comment: @internety But it doesn't have href or say it doesn't have any other attributes. And what they are showing is exactly how I'm currently doing it, fetching all 'div' and going through one by one to search for what I'm looking for. Was wondering if there is a one search solution, without having to parse everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
# coding: utf-8

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title> Last chicken leg on stock! Only 500$ !!! </title>
  </head>
  </body>
    <div id="layer1" class="class1">
        <div id="layer2" class="class2">
            <div id="layer3" class="class3">
                <div id="layer4" class="class4">
                    <div id="layer5" class="class5">
                      <p>My chicken has <span style="color:blue">ONE</span> leg :P</p>
                        <div id="layer6" class="class6">
                            <div id="layer7" class="class7">
                              <div id="chicken_surname" class="chicken">eat me</div>
                                <div id="layer8" class="class8">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re
soup = BS(html_doc, "lxml")


# (tag -> text) direction is pretty obvious that way
tag = soup.find('div', class_="chicken")
tag2 = soup.find('div', {'id':"chicken_surname"})
print('\n###### by_cls:')
print(tag)
print('\n###### by_id:')
print(tag2)

# but can be tricky when need to find tag by substring
tag_by_str = soup.find(string="eat me")
tag_by_sub = soup.find(string="eat")
tag_by_resub = soup.find(string=re.compile("eat"))
print('\n###### tag_by_str:')
print(tag_by_str)
print('\n###### tag_by_sub:')
print(tag_by_sub)
print('\n###### tag_by_resub:')
print(tag_by_resub)

# there are more than one way to access underlying strings
# both are different - see results
tag = soup.find('p')

print('\n###### .text attr:')
print( tag.text, type(tag.text) )

print('\n###### .strings generator:')
for s in tag.strings:   # strings is an generator object
    print s, type(s)

# note that .strings generator returns list of bs4.element.NavigableString elements
# so we can use them to navigate, for example accessing their parents:
print('\n###### NavigableString parents:')
for s in tag.strings:  
    print s.parent

# or even grandparents :)
print('\n###### grandparents:')
for s in tag.strings:  
    print s.parent.parent
```

Comment: My question is in the case of more than one of the same tag for strings that you are looking for, I would have to go through all of them in order to find the target tag, correct -- e.g. say there were two `p` tags, then `tag = soup.find('p')
` wouldn't necessarily work? What I'm looking for is a way to find the tag of a string in one attempt, without having to parse everything.

Comment: @Jo Ko: "without having to parse everything"
IMO each element search within HTML document requires parsing entire document :)
    
different approach, used when need to parse document available only partially (i.e. long-pooled HTTP) is to use incremental parser, see [parse HTML incrementally](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#incremental-event-parsing) for more info on that method.