# Python BeautifulSoup Class function returns full text, how do I split so each paragraph is clearly defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a soupFindALL and it returns the full body of text. e.g
Website sample:
Plant aaa Type aa
Plant bb Type b
Plant cccc Type ccc

`<table class="neither">` covers all the text above
`<td class="neither--top">` is the label for each one so I don't know of a way to get the three results individually.

The below script is what I run

```
for item_e in soup.findAll('table', {'class' : 'neither'}):
        Plant = item_e.get_text(strip=True)
```

This returns the full body of text:
`Plant aaa TypeaaPlant bb TypebPlant cccc Type cc`

I want there to be a clear distinction between the three items, it can be on the same line e.g
`Plant aaa Typeaa Plant bb Typeb Plant cccc Type cc`

How do I do that?

Comment: provide a link to page you parsing or its code on pastebin

Comment: http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/44093979?search_identifier=fc7471aa4c7376edab1e2e71afd595d8#oTVDTIU7JA50J5A0.97

Comment: See link above and if you see the table class neither which is the recent sales section on the right hand side of the page

Comment: [RTFM](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or at least [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320448/4387299) to find out how to navigate between html elements using bs4. 



`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup = BS(html, "lxml")
ourtable = soup.find('table', class_="neither")
for child in ourtable.childGenerator():
    print(child)`