# Extract a certain content from html using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I have been trying to extract

```
Bacillus circulans
```

from following html:

```
<tr><th class="th10" align="left" valign="top" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><nobr>Organism</nobr></th>
<td class="td10" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><div style="width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"><a href="/kegg-bin/show_organism?tax=1397">ag</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Addendum (Bacillus circulans)<br>
</div></td></tr>
```

but I am not sure which tag it is under and how to get into that tag.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you,
Xp

edit: I am actually trying to get bacillus circulans from KEGG addenlum page

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'http://www.kegg.jp/entry/ag:CAA27061'


page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()


soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('div')

for i in tags.contents:
        print i
```

Above is what I know how to do. Since there are more organisms to retrieve, I don't think I can use 're' to match a patter. I want to find a tag that associates with `Addenlum org`, and fetch the organism names

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: everything you're asking for is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320448/4387299)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual preliminaries.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''\
... <tr><th class="th10" align="left" valign="top" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><nobr>Organism</nobr></th><td class="td10" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><div style="width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"><a href="/kegg-bin/show_organism?tax=1397">ag</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Addendum (Bacillus circulans)<br></div></td></tr>''', 'lxml')
```

Then I `prettify` the `soup` to see what I'm up against.

```
>>> for line in soup.prettify().split('\n'):
...     print(line)
... 
<html>
 <body>
  <tr>
   <th align="left" class="th10" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; border-style: solid" valign="top">
    <nobr>
     Organism
    </nobr>
   </th>
   <td class="td10" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px; border-style: solid">
    <div style="width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden">
     <a href="/kegg-bin/show_organism?tax=1397">
      ag
     </a>
     Addendum (Bacillus circulans)
     <br/>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </body>
</html>
```

I can see that the string you want is one of three items that constitute the `contents` of a `div` element. My first step is to identify that element, and I use its `style` attribute.

```
>>> parentDiv = soup.find('div', attrs={"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"})
```

I examine the three items in its `contents`, and I'm reminded that strings don't have a `name`; it's `None`.

```
>>> for item in parentDiv.contents:
...     item, item.name
...     
(<a href="/kegg-bin/show_organism?tax=1397">ag</a>, 'a')
('\xa0\xa0Addendum (Bacillus circulans)', None)
(<br/>, 'br')
```

Then to isolate that string I can use:

```
>>> BC_string = [_ for _ in parentDiv.contents if not _.name]
>>> BC_string 
['\xa0\xa0Addendum (Bacillus circulans)']
```

Edit: Given information from comment, this is how to handle one page. Find the heading for 'Organism' (in a `nobr` elment), then look for the `div` that contains the desired text relative to that element. Filter out the string(s) from other elements that are `contents` of that `div`, then use a regex to obtain the parenthesised name of the organism. If the regex fails then offer the whole string.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> soup_2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.kegg.jp/entry/ag:CAA27061').content, 'lxml')
>>> organism = soup_2.find_all('nobr', string='Organism')
>>> parentDiv = organism[0].fetchParents()[0].fetchNextSiblings()[0].find_all('div')[0]
>>> desiredContent = [_.strip() for _ in parentDiv.contents if not _.name and _.strip()]
>>> if desiredContent:
...     m = bs4.re.match('[^\(]*\(([^\)]+)', desiredContent[0])
...     if m:
...         name = m.groups()[0]
...     else:
...         name = "Couldn't match content of " + desiredContent
...         
>>> name
'Bacillus circulans'
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python


import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'http://www.kegg.jp/entry/ag:CAA27061'


page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()


soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('div')` I tried to adopt your code to a larger scale, but I am failing to get into that particular content. This is where I got stuck. And also I have other similar entries to retrieve the organism name.

Comment: What is it that you actually want from that page?

Comment: Bill, the name: bacillus circulans in this example. The reality is this program has to retrieve the web couple times with different organism entry ids( In this example, entry id as you can see is `ag:CAA27061`) thus different bacterial names.

Comment: So you know the page identifiers such as 'ag:CAA27061' and, having loaded such a page, you want the content of the entry labelled 'Organism'

Comment: yes correct sir. I have a list of identfiers, I will feed them to the program, and it will look for the corresponding page, scrape off the bacterial names.

Comment: Bill: I will just use `div = soup.find_all('div'); for i in divs: stuff = i.contents for j in stuff: if "Addendum" in j: return j` as for now. This is gonna take a great amount of time if I have thousands of ids, so if you know of a better way, please let me know. But as of now, I will put your reply as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html='''<tr><th class="th10" align="left" valign="top" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><nobr>Organism</nobr></th>
<td class="td10" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><div style="width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"><a href="/kegg-bin/show_organism?tax=1397">ag</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Addendum (Bacillus circulans)<br>
</div></td></tr>'''
html=soup(html)
print(html.text)
```

A simple way that prints

```
Organism
ag  Addendum (Bacillus circulans)
```

Then you can

```
print(html.text.split('(')[1].split(')')[0])
```

Which prints Bacillus circulans

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using bs4 and regular expressions.

**BeautifulSoup Part**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
h = """
<tr><th class="th10" align="left" valign="top" style="border-color:#000; 
border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><nobr>Organism</nobr>
</th>
<td class="td10" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px; 
border-style: solid"><div style="width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-
y:hidden"><a href="/kegg-bin/show_organism?
tax=1397">ag</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Addendum (Bacillus circulans)<br>
</div></td></tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Your content lies inside a `<div>` tag.

```
tag = soup.find('div')
t = tag.text #'ag\xa0\xa0Addendum (Bacillus circulans)\n'
```

**Regular Expression Part**

```
import re
m = re.match(('(.*)\((.*)\).*', t)
ans = m.group(2)  #Bacillus circulans
```