# BeautifulSoup Cannot Find Tag li

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, html-lists

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>>html_text = '<li>Location:<a href="tweetLocation">tweetLocation</a></li>'
>>>soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
>>>print soup.find('li', text=re.compile(r'^Location.*'))
```

I am getting answer as none.
Can anyone tell me how to find that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag)

Answer (score 1):

`text` argument (which is now renamed to `string`) actually checks a [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) of an element to match the desired criteria - in this case a regular expression `^Location.*`.

Now, there is something special about the `.string` attribute - *it's value would be `None` if a tag has multiple children*:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what
>   .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

And, your `li` element has actually multiple children - a text node `Location:` and an `a` element. Hence, no results.

Instead, locate the text element and then get to the desired element:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: html_text = '<li>Location:<a href="tweetLocation">tweetLocation</a></li>'

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

In [5]: soup.find(text=re.compile(r'^Location.*')).find_parent('li')
Out[5]: <li>Location:<a href="tweetLocation">tweetLocation</a></li>

In [6]: soup.find(text=re.compile(r'^Location.*')).next_sibling.get_text()
Out[6]: 'tweetLocation'
```