# Reading specific content from website and display using python

Tags: python

The code below is what i have currently done, but i am struggling to get it working properly... 
hope you can help :)

```
#A python programme which shows the current price of bitcoin.
#(a well-known crypto-currency.)

import urllib
import urllib2

def webConnect():
aResp = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/overview/GBP")
web_pg = aResp.read();

print web_pg
```

def main():
    webConnect()

main()

g = Grab()
g.go(address)

btc_div = g.xpath('//*/div[class="ng-binding"]')

val = btc_div.xpath(u"dl/dt[contains(text(),'%s')]/../dd/text()" % 'if only that tag contains this text')
print val[0]

Comment: Your code format is a bit too messed up. It would have been a lot better and easy to use BeautifulSoup when it comes to extracting specific contents like stock price, currency values etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use beautifulsoup library.

This question has example of finding tags by text : [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag)

Tutorial : https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out now :)