# BS4: Comment in tag breaks string attribute and search capability

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In BeautifulSoup4, if you call `.string` on a Tag element, the text contained inside the tag should be returned.

But, if inside a tag there is a comment, the `.string` attribute suddenly returns `None`.

The `.text` attribute seems to work nonetheless, but calling `find` with the supposedly still-working `text` attribute does not work anymore. 
So, if there is no comment, `find` works, if there is a comment, `find` does not work.

Here is a MWE:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def test(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    tag = soup.find('span')
    print("TEXT {}: {}".format(type(tag.text), tag.text))
    print("STRING {}: {}".format(type(tag.string), tag.string))
    found = soup.find('span', text="Hello")
    print("Found: {}\n".format("Yes" if found != None else "No"))

test('<span>Hello</span>')
test('<span><!-- AA -->Hello</span>')
```

Here is the output:

```
TEXT <class 'str'>: Hello
STRING <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>: Hello
Found: Yes

TEXT <class 'str'>: Hello
STRING <class 'NoneType'>: None
Found: No
```

The question is: why is this behavior displayed, and how can I restore the `find` functionality?

P.S. `find_all()` does not return any children for any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tag has only one child of type `NavigableString` then only `.string` will work. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string.

Your problem is same as [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag). That has few solutions for your problem.