# How do I search for tags in BS4 containing a given string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

In BeautifulSoup4, how do I search for tags with text containing a specific string? For example, when searching for 'skyrim' I want to print the contents (e.g. the game title) of each tag containing the string 'skyrim'.

I've tried using

```
    if 'skyrim' in tag.string:
```

But it never prints anything.

**Full definition:**

```
def search(self):
    steam_results = self.soup.find_all('span', class_='title')

    itr = 1
    for tag in steam_results:
        if self.title in tag.string:  # <--- Not working
            print(str(itr) + ': ' + tag.string + '\n')
            itr = itr + 1
```

Sample of `steam_results`:

```
>>> steam_results
[<span class="title">The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Special Edition</span>,
 <span class="title">Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE)</span>, 
 <span class="title">Enderal</span>, ...]
```

**Expected result:**

1. The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Special Edition
2. Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE)

**Actual result:** does not print anything

Comment: Try the getText() method. tag.getText()

Comment: mention data of `steam_results`.

Comment: seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag

Comment: getText() results in the same error.

Comment: Now, it seems good.

Comment: usually `get_Text()` works here. But if it is giving you error, provide the website `url` from where you are scrapping so I can test my self where actually problem is.

Comment: get_Text() gives me `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Here is the url: `https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=skyrim`

Comment: @CharlesMorgan see answer and let me know if still there is any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is sub-string checking because it is `case-sensitive`. If you check with `skyrim`, you will get empty results because no `title` contains `skyrim` instead they contain `Skyrim`. So, compare it with lower-case titles like this,

```
steam_results = soup.find_all('span', class_='title')
for steam in steam_results:
    if 'skyrim' in steam.getText().lower():
        print(steam.getText())
```

Output:

```
The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Special Edition
The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim VR
Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE)
The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Special Edition - Creation Club
```

Comment: Alternatively, suggest for a case insensitive testing like `if 'skyrim' in steam.getText().lower():` so everything is converted and compared in lower case.

Comment: Thanks for nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `soup.find_all(string=re.compile("your_string_here")`to get the texts and then use `.parent` to get the tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html="""
<p id="1">Hi there</p>
<p id="2">hello<p>
<p id="2">hello there<p>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print([tag.parent for tag in soup.find_all(string=re.compile("there"))])
```

Output

```
[<p id="1">Hi there</p>, <p id="2">hello there<p>\n</p></p>]
```