# How can i find a span tag with a specific value and then find the parent a tag it is in?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website for deals, specifically when a product is 100% off.

How can I find all span tags within this page, if any, that have a value of -100%, for example `<span>-100%</span>`.

If one of these is found how can I get the parent a tag that it is nested in.

I am using python 3.x and beautiful soup.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
link = 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price_ASC&ignore_preferences=1&page=524'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
parents = [element.parent for element in soup.find_all("span", string="-80%")]
print(parents)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:has` and `:contains` with bs4 4.7.1 to specify your request. The page number of listings keep changing so bear that in mind.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price_ASC&ignore_preferences=1&page=520', headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla\5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content,"lxml")
items= [(item.text.strip(), item['href']) for item in soup.select('a:has(span:contains("-80%"))')]
print(items)
```

Comment: I ran exactly this and got an error of
'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: you need bs4 4.7.1 which is a good idea to have anyway as it is more robust and has more functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag) for a more in depth discussion of a similar problem.

In short, you need to use the bs4 methods `find_all` and `parent`, for example like this:

```
parents = [element.parent for element in soup.find_all("span", string="-100%")]
```

`soup` is the bs4 object of your HTML code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps but for some reason that I can't figure out, sometimes it wont find the tag. For example running the code i have added above it returns nothing.

Comment: I also don't see any occurrences of '-80%' on that page, to be honest? :-)

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake I worked it out. Accidentally I was logged in on steam and this was having unexpected effects on the search results not being the same as the page python would get. This works flawlessly but instead of getting the parent one above is there a way I can get the parent multiple steps up and retrieve the a  tag with the href link in?
I'm not that familiar with html so I am not sure if this all makes sense what I'm trying to do

Comment: sure. one naive implementation but which might work is to simply chain multiple `parent` calls: `element.parent.parent.parent` for example.