# How to find element by 2 text?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For exaple, I have HTML code like this. And I want to find this by "T-shirt name" and "Color - T-shirt". How to do this? And I want to find this color because I have a few more T-shirt with the same name but different color.

```html
<article>
  <div class="article">
    <a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/t-shirt">
      <img src="//blablabla.jpg" alt="asdasdas" width="150" height="150">
      <h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/t-shirt/">T-shirt name</a>
      </h1>
      <p><a class="name-link" href="/shop/t-shirt/">>Color</a></p>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="article">
    <a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/t-shirt">
      <img src="//blablabla.jpg" alt="asdasdas" width="150" height="150">
      <h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/t-shirt/">T-shirt name</a>
      </h1>
      <p><a class="name-link" href="/shop/t-shirt/">>second Color</a></p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? What did you try?

Comment: Do you know [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library?

Comment: @abdusco I tried find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='T-shirt name']") but it throws me away "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:"

Comment: Your question is not clear do you want to find an element by the text of the other element?

Comment: @konto211541 please shear more of the HTML

Comment: @MosheSlavin i want to find by text "T-shirt name" and "Color"

Comment: Can you check my answer.This will give you what you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located` and following `xpath` to achieve it.

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//h1/a[@class='name-link' and contains(.,'T-shirt name')]")))
for element in elements :

    print('T shirt name : ' +element.text)
    print('T Shirt color : ' + element.find_element_by_xpath("./following::p/a[@class='name-link']").text)
```

You need to import followings to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

EDITED With click option for a particular color.

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//h1/a[@class='name-link' and contains(.,'T-shirt name')]")))
for element in elements :

    print('T shirt name : ' +element.text)
    print('T Shirt color : ' + element.find_element_by_xpath("./following::p/a[@class='name-link']").text)
    if element.find_element_by_xpath("./following::p/a[@class='name-link']").text=='RED':
        element.find_element_by_xpath("./following::p/a[@class='name-link']").click()
```

Comment: Ok that work, now how to click on e.g. T Shirt collor == "Red"?

Comment: Check the second print value with If condition and click.I am away now shall I come back later

Comment: @konto211541 : Check the Edited section

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for parsing
`soup.find_all("a", string="T-shirt name")`

[similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959218/7247551)