# Limit depth of tag.text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just can't get it right. BeautifulSoup4 is so confusing.

I'm trying to fix unrendered Markdown references in HTML text. The regex is:

```
REF = re.compile(r"\[(?P<title>.+?)\]\[(?P<identifier>.*?)\]")
```

Since apparently BS4 uses `match` with regular expressions, I made the regex wider with

```
REF = re.compile(r".*\[(?P<title>.+?)\]\[(?P<identifier>.*?)\].*", re.DOTALL)
```

The goal is to find such strings and replace them with actual `<a>` links, but not if they are in a `<code>` tag (whatever the depth). I have a mapping to get the URL from the `identifier`.

`[<code>title<code>][identifier]` should be matched, but `<code>[title][identifier]</code>` should not.

If the input is:

```
<p>[<code>title<code>][identifier]</p>
```

The output should be:

```
<p><a id="identifier" href="http://example.com"><code>title<code></a></p>
```

However the following input should stay untouched:

```
<p><code>[title][identifier]</code></p>
```

I tried the following:

```
tags = [tag.parent for tag in soup.find_all(text=REF) if not tag.find_parent("code")]
```

...but it was missing tags. I found an explanation in this post: [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag). It seems `text` (or the new name `string`, though I found the behavior to be different) will return `None` when there are other tags in the tag, meaning the tag `<p>[<code>title<code>][identifier]</p>` will not be matched.

I also thought the post gave the solution:

```
tags = list(
    soup.find_all(
        lambda tag: tag.name != "code" and
                    not tag.find_parent("code") and
                    REF.search(tag.text)
    )
)
```

...but now instead of giving me tags close to the leaves, it returns root tags like `<html>` and `<body>`, because `tag.text` returns the *full, recursive text of all descendants*. Then of course these tags contains text matching the regex, but *inside `<code>` tags*.

The best solution, I think, would be to try the regex against the tag's text limited to a certain depth. If depth-1 text of `<p>[<code>title</code>][identifier]</p>` is `[ ][identifier]` and depth-2 text of the same tag is `[<code>title</code>][identifier]`, then depth-2 is all I need.

Is there a way to do that? Or do you have any other solution in mind? I thought maybe I could iterate on all the tags from the leaves to the root, breadth-first, but I'll still have the same problem with `tag.text` returning all the descendants' text as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought a lot about it, and eventually used another method.

Instead of trying to select tags with complex filters / iteration / recursion on the tree, I went with full strings and regular expressions.

Since I don't want to touch code blocks at all, I replace `code` nodes in all the tree with `NavigableString` instantiated with random, unique values. These values are placeholders that we will use later to restore the original code blocks. The values are built with a seed, that I make sure appears nowhere in the HTML, and a random, unique integer between 0 and 1000000. I populate a dict with placeholders as keys, and code blocks as values (strings).

Then I get the big HTML string with `str(soup)`, and I simply run my `re.sub` on the whole HTML!

Once it's done, I run a second `re.sub` with a custom `repl` function ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub)), matching my placeholders and replacing them with the previously stored code blocks.

Tada! It works perfectly.

Here is the Placeholder class:

```
class Placeholder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids = {}
        self.seed = None
        self.set_seed()

    def store(self, value):
        i = self.get_id()
        while i in self.ids:
            i = self.get_id()
        self.ids[i] = value
        return i

    def get_id(self):
        return f"{self.seed}{random.randint(0, 1000000)}"

    def set_seed(self):
        self.seed = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=16))

    def hide_code_tags(self, soup):

        def recursive_hide(tag):
            if hasattr(tag, "contents"):
                for i in range(len(tag.contents)):
                    child = tag.contents[i]
                    if child.name == "code":
                        tag.contents[i] = NavigableString(self.store(str(child)))
                    else:
                        recursive_hide(child)

        recursive_hide(soup)

        return str(soup)

    def restore_code_tags(self, soup_str):
        def replace_placeholder(match):
            placeholder = match.groups()[0]
            return self.ids[placeholder]

        return re.sub(rf"({self.seed}\d+)", replace_placeholder, soup_str)
```

And how to use it:

```
placeholder = Placeholder()
while re.search(placeholder.seed, html) or any(placeholder.seed in url for url in MY_URLS_MAP.values()):
    placeholder.set_seed()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup_str = placeholder.hide_code_tags(soup)
fixed_soup_str = AUTO_REF.sub(MY_REPL_FUNCTION, soup_str)
final_soup_str = placeholder.restore_code_tags(fixed_soup_str)
```