# Does BeautifulSoup can locate the element basing on contained text?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I couldn't find any information in docs. Selenium have contains() to locate the element which may include some part of text. Is anything like that availabe in BS ?

Comment: Is this question - [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag) - relevant? If it is not, can you provide more details, maybe with an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag)

Comment: Hi, already changed the way of achieving that and used lxml.html.fromstring :)