# Get text and child from a span with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am in a specific situation where I want to extract both the text and a child node from a span:

```
<span>condition:<b>good</b></span>
```

However, when I try to select the span with the text:

```
x = soup.find('span', text=re.compile(r'^condition:$'))
```

I get `None` back.

I've verified that that tag exists in the HTML document I am working with.

And I can't figure out how to get the internal  tag either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Following have the same issue [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag)

You can separate the function to solve the problem, like this:

```
def find_all_with_regex(soup, target_tag, regex):
    elements = soup.find_all(target_tag)
    return list(filter(lambda tag_found: regex.match(tag_found.text), elements))

print(find_all_with_regex(soup, 'span', re.compile(r'^condition:.*')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following css selector.

```
print(soup.select_one('span:contains("condition:")').text)
```

**Code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<span>condition:<b>good</b></span>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('span:contains("condition:")').text)
```