# BeautifulSoup's find() can't match Chinese character

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.paopaoche.net/psp/280873.html"
res = requests.get(url)
res.encoding="gb2312"
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
tag1 = bsObj.find("dd", {"class":"left"}).find(class_="xq").find("em", text="游戏类型")
print(tag1)
```

The terminal return "None". If I change `find("em", text="游戏类型")` to `find("em", text="1993")`, terminal return correct result. Where is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag)

Comment: thx,that is the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is slightly modified code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.paopaoche.net/psp/280873.html"
res = requests.get(url)
res.encoding="gb2312"
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(res.content.decode('gb2312'), 'html5lib')

tag1 = bsObj.select("dd.left .xq")[0].find(lambda tag: tag.name == "em" and "游戏类型" in tag.text)

print(tag1)
```

"em" element contains not only text searched, but also another text and child elements, so it's needed to find elements containing search expression (not having text equal to search expression).